# Bind elements from array created by pushing another array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I want to list an array of data type `Formacion` created by pushing data from another array.

This is how I create the type "Formacion".

```
export class Formacion {
    nombre: string;

  constructor(a){
    this.nombre = a;
  }

  getFormacion(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

}
```

This is how I create the array that will receive the data

```
public arrayB: Formacion[] = new Array();
```

This is how I loop on `ArrayA` and get a value on each loop to push it to `ArrayB`

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.arrayA.length; i++){
    let form: Formacion = new Formacion(this.arrayA[i].nombre);
    this.arrayB.push(form);
}
```

This is how I print `ArrayB`

```
console.log(this.arrayB);
```

And this is the result

[image]

How can I make a list of `nombres` of `Formacion`? I am trying the following code but it is not working.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of arrayB; let j = index" [attr.data-index]="j">{{item.nombre}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does **not working** mean?

Comment: It means it does not work: its not showing results.. cant get "nombre" from undefined.

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in plunker/stackblitz. I see no obvious error in your code.